# set panel height sencha -touch

Tags: css, sencha-touch, height, panel

I am New In sencha -touch and need your help.

I add new panel and want to set the height of this panel in css.

```
 this.clockContainer = new Ext.Panel({
id:'clock',
    html:'00:00'
});
#clock {height:142px}
```

however,sencha calculates the height style to 91px (according to the html content) and ignores my css.

I dont want to add the height property to the panel like this:

```
this.clockContainer = new Ext.Panel({
id:'clock',
    html:'00:00',
    height:'142px'
});
```

what can I do?How can I prevent sencha calculates the height?

thank you.

edit: if I set the  height property to '142px' it works fine but if I set it to '8.06em' senchs ignores it and calculate itself.

Comment: Incidentally, why don't you want to use the height property? would like to understand your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `cls` attributes to your `Ext.Panel` like so

```
this.clockContainer = new Ext.Panel({
    id:'clock',
    html:'00:00',
    cls:'clock-panel'
});
```

Then in your CSS you add this

```
.clock-panel .x-panel-body{
    height:142px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Also, CSS in Sencha-Touch is way easier when you use Firebug

Comment: ese codido css va en el mismo codido .js o en un archivo externo? y si va en un archivo externo como se haría? ando buscando la forma de colocar estilos .css aparte del .js pero no hallo la forma, alguien puede ayudarme?